# Blackhole 2ch broke my Mac audio output?

Tags: mac, audio

I was trying out Blackhole 2ch for audio capture when I was having some trouble with OBS, and have since uninstalled it. (downloaded the uninstall software and ran it)

But ever since I uninstalled, in every recording software, even quicktime player, the audio output on my Mac has 0 options. Just says some variation on “not available”. It doesn’t even give me the option to capture my macbook mic audio, it’s just completely blank.

The output itself is fine, in the system preferences it’s there, as well as when using the Audio MIDI Setup. It’s completely normal accept when I try to record anything.

Any ideas? I’ve had two software updates since, have deleted and redownloaded all recording softwares, and have redownloaded Blackhole 2ch to see if that would change anything. Nothing has worked. I’m completely lost. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your recording softwares' list of available input audio devices to the question. We also need an explanation of what normal looks like in practice since that description isn’t helping us answer your issue.